# Flipping through pages on a notebook (HTML5) using Selenium WebDriver (Java)

Tags: html, animation, selenium, drag-and-drop, webdriver

I want to flip through a notebook, **without using any buttons** or something like that, but actually clicking on the active element of the page or by dragging the page to get to the next one. The notebook is something similar to [this one](http://www.20thingsilearned.com/en-US/foreword/3). I tried many different approaches but failed.

The code I am trying to get to work is:

```
    WebElement page= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pages']/section[4]/div"));
    Actions kkk = new Actions(driver);
    Actions flip= kkk.moveToElement(page, 780, 200);
    flip.click().build().perform();
```

I also tried the next approach :

```
flip.perform();
Thread.sleep(200); //to allow the mouse to hover and activate the page
flip.click().perform();
```

Nothing works, the mouse hovers over the neccesary place and if I try to click in the same place, it just resets and the page rolls back flat.

Also, is there any way finding the neccesarry place (the active spot of the element) without using Offset (coordinates), I can't think of any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems more on the lines of `drag and drop`.

Try doing something like this

```
WebElement draggable = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pages']/section[4]/div")); 
new Actions(browser).dragAndDropBy(draggable, 200, 10).build().perform();
```

Based on

`org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions.dragAndDropBy(WebElement source, int xOffset, int yOffset)`

**UPDATE**

---

or this way

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("source"));
WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.name("target"));

(new Actions(driver)).dragAndDrop(element, target).perform();
```

**UPDATE 2**

---

Or this way

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

   Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(someElement)
       .moveToElement(otherElement)
       .release(otherElement)
       .build();

   dragAndDrop.perform();
```

Comment: But the xpath method or any source destination drag and dorp method doesnt really work because the active field isnt the page itself but only a small precentage of the far right side of the page. So I cant click the page in the middle and drag, it wont do anything. I already tried drag and drop, and also clickAndHold and moving.